# How to post data to html form via java?

Tags: java, html, forms, post

I have this html form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="links" id="links" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px; width: 428px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px; height: 149px; "></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="uploadtype" value="links">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit"></button>
        </form>
```

How to write some data in the text area and click the submit button using java?

Comment: Are you attempting to send multipart from Java code? If so do you have thin Java client or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try apache http client
[Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)

And try latest "version" [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)

[Example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java)